Rails 7 - How to update a model with skipping the validation?
When I try to update some attributes in a model
my_model.update!(attr1: 'val 1', attr2: 'val 2', attr3: 'val 3') 

I get an error
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: MyModel must exist, MyModel2 must exist (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)

Is there a way to skip the validation directly with the update method?

If you take a look at the source code for update! you'll see that it's merely assign_attributes followed by save!. (as shown in the answer below)

You have to use save which has :validate option:
my_model.assign_attributes(attr1: 'val 1', attr2: 'val 2', attr3: 'val 3') 
my_model.save!(validate: false)


See: Active Record Validations - Skipping Validations for a complete list of methods that skip validations.
